# как вставить знак пунктуации " внутри открытия и закрытия скобок " "

Tags: c++

я использую `constexpr string_view test;`
и мне нужно добавить этот знак `"` в `test = """`
но компилятор ругается он так не понимает где закрытия и открытия скобок.

Comment: [Escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape), [Raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

Comment: Спасибо помогло, я сделал так "\"" надеюсь это правильно

Answer (score 2):

Используй символ экранирования `\`

```
constexpr std::string_view test("\"");
```

Не забывай, что `string_view` появилась в 17 версии языка